# adding a row to the react table by clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-data-grid

I am looking to add a new row to the existing table. Is there any way achieving that I have read the api of the reactdatagrid but no luck in finding it. any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First map you need the data you need to render in table to your component state. Let's say to an array.

```
tableData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tim',
    age: 25,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Jane',
    age: 22,
  },
]
```

And populate the table with that state array. Then add a button and on button click just push some empty value to the array.

```
const { tableData } = this.state;
tableData.push({ id: null, name: '', age: null});
this.setState({ tableData });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new entry on your data that you feed on the table. So setState when you press a button to append the data.